# YouTrack Connector for different clients

Tags: netbeans, connector, youtrack

Is it possible to query YouTrack issues from a different client other than the web client? For example, is there any connector available for listing YouTrack issues from a different IDE other than Idea (Netbeans or anything else etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a ReSharper plugin for YouTrack: https://github.com/JetBrains/YouTrackForReSharper. Furthermore, here's a description of YouTrack REST API: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD3/YouTrack+REST+API+Reference which you can use if you want to integrate YouTrack with almost any kind of tool.

Alexander

Comment: What I understand is ReSharper plugin if good for Visual Studio? Is there any plugin for Netbeans?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no. At lease I'm not aware of any.